# How to find inverse CDF for the range of normal values (probit for a range)?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Here's an example from [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1.96):

[image: 95% of the area under the normal distribution lies within 1.96 standard deviations of the mean.]

I have a fixed probability $p=0.95$, and I need to find the $X$ for the range symmetric around the mean which limits the normal distribution so that there's a $p$ chance for the value to be in that range.

The inverse CDF, or the [probit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit), can help to find the value which cuts the area into two parts. But I can't get if it can be transformed somehow to get the value for the range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia page,
$$\Phi^{-1}(p) = \sqrt2\operatorname{erf}^{-1}(2p - 1)\qquad \text{for} \qquad p\in(0,1)$$ and the problem is the inverse of the error function.

You could get an *approximation* of $p$ using
$$\text{erf}(x)\approx \sqrt{1-\exp\Big(-\frac 4 {\pi}\,\frac{1+\alpha\, x^2}{1+\beta \,x^2}\,x^2 \Big)}$$ where
$$\alpha=\frac{10-\pi ^2}{5 (\pi -3) \pi } \qquad \text{and} \qquad \beta=\frac{120-60 \pi +7 \pi ^2}{15 (\pi -3) \pi }$$ which can easily be inversed (at the price of a quadratic in $x^2$.

Othermise, numerical methods such as Newton.

Comment: Oh, so the `inverf` function will do the job? Then I can use implementation from here: http://www.meta-numerics.net/Samples/FunctionCalculator.aspx Thank you!

Comment: It's even can be counted in excel with: `SQRT(GAMMAINV(p,0.5,1)) * SQRT(2)`