# Sum of binomial coefficients so that the sum equals ${n\choose n/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics

I am trying to find $m$ (either exact or order of $m$ in terms of $n$) such that:

$$\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{n}{k} = {n\choose \frac{n}{2}}$$

I was thinking of applying Stirling's approximation for factorials for large $n$, so $\displaystyle\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}\sim\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{n}}$. But looking at $\displaystyle{n\choose k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ and that the sum over $k$ starts from $k=0$, I cannot use Stirling's approximation for $k!$ for small $k$.

I was also looking at sum of binomial coefficients on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Sums_of_binomial_coefficients) which gives an upper bound for the sum and so am wondering if getting an upper bound is the best we can do or if we can find $m$ precisely?

Comment: There certainly isn’t a value $m$ for all $n$ with exact equality.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews True, I guess I am looking for the order of $m$ in terms of $n$ then.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. It is OK in the real domain.

Comment: Improved using the upper bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting problem from a numerical point of view.

Transposed in the real domain, you are looking for $m$ such that

$$\color{blue}{\frac{\, _2F_1(1,m-n+1;m+2;-1)}{\Gamma (m+2) \,\,\Gamma (n-m)} =\frac{2^n}{\Gamma (n+1)}-\frac{1}{\Big[\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)\Big]^2}}$$ where $m$ and $n$ are real numbers.

This equation is not difficult to solve using Newton method with $m_0=\frac n 2$. This starting point is justified by the left part of the trivial double inequality
$$\binom{n}{m} \leq\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{n}{k}\leq (m+1)\binom{n}{m}$$ which means that we already know that $m \leq \frac n 2$. I did not find any simple way to use the right part of the above inequality (*this is no more true : have a look at the* $\color{red}{\text{ update}}$) .

For example, for $n=10$, the iterates are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & m_k \\
 0 & 5.000000000 \\
 1 & 3.419647982 \\
 2 & 3.407971414 \\
 3 & 3.407943361
\end{array}
\right)$$

Below are some results (I let you rounding the results the way you want).
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & m \\
 10 & 3.40794 \\
 20 & 7.41879 \\
 30 & 11.5964 \\
 40 & 15.8702 \\
 50 & 20.2093 \\
 60 & 24.5969 \\
 70 & 29.0227 \\
 80 & 33.4793 \\
 90 & 37.9619 \\
 100 & 42.4665 \\
 110 & 46.9903 \\
 120 & 51.5309 \\
 130 & 56.0864 \\
 140 & 60.6554 \\
 150 & 65.2365 \\
 160 & 69.8287 \\
 170 & 74.4310 \\
 180 & 79.0426 \\
 190 & 83.6628 \\
 200 & 88.2910 \\
 210 & 92.9267 \\
 220 & 97.5694 \\
 230 & 102.219 \\
 240 & 106.874 \\
 250 & 111.535 \\
 260 & 116.202 \\
 270 & 120.874 \\
 280 & 125.550 \\
 290 & 130.232 \\
 300 & 134.918
\end{array}
\right)$$

This looks to be very close to linearity. Using these numbers, a quick and dirty linear regression for $m=a +b \,n$ leads to $R^2=0.999957$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & -2.6778 & 0.2028 & \{-3.0938,-2.2618\} \\
 b & +0.4561 & 0.0011 & \{+0.4538,+0.4585\} \\
\end{array}$$

Using this empirical model for $n=400$, it gives $m=179.775$ while the solution is $181.986$.

As I wrote in comments, this also works for non integer values of $n$. For $n=123.456$, $m=53.1037$.

**Update**

I managed to use
$$\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{n}{k}\leq (m+1)\binom{n}{m}$$ defining the function
$$f(m)=(m+1)\binom{n}{m}- {n\choose \frac{n}{2}}$$ which was expanded as a series to
$O\left(\left(m-\frac{n}{2}\right)^3\right)$. Solving the quadratic, the approximate solution is given by
$$m=\frac n 2-\frac{n}{1+\sqrt{n} \sqrt{(n+2) \psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)-\frac{3
   n+8}{n^2}}}$$ which is a much better starting point as shown below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 50 & 20.5142 & 20.2093 \\
 100 & 43.4413 & 42.4665 \\
 150 & 66.8507 & 65.2365 \\
 200 & 90.5099 & 88.2910 \\
 250 & 114.329 & 111.535 \\
 300 & 138.261 & 134.918
\end{array}
\right)$$

The asymptotics of the approximation is
$$m=\frac n2 \left(1-\sqrt{\frac 2 n}+\frac 1 n+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)\right)$$

**Update**

I found later [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103280/asymptotics-for-a-partial-sum-of-binomial-coefficients); @user940 gave a very interesting asymptotic approximation. Adapted to your problem, we look for the solution $m$ of the equation
$$2^{n-1} \left(1-\text{erf}\left(\frac{n-2 m}{\sqrt{2n}
   }\right)\right)=\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}$$ that is to say
$$\text{erf}\left(\frac{n-2 m}{\sqrt{2n} }\right)=1-\frac{2\, \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \,\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}$$ This can be inversed using *approximations* of the error function (have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3279660/how-to-find-inverse-cdf-for-the-range-of-normal-values-probit-for-a-range/3279672#3279672)).

This would give
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 50  & 20.7060 \\
 100 & 42.9608 \\
 150 & 65.7299 \\
 200 & 88.7840 \\
 250 & 112.028 \\
 300 & 135.410
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is significantly better for large values of $n$.

Concerning the asymptotics of $n$, using
$$\text{erf}(x)=1+e^{-x^2} \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }
   x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right)$$ we have
$$m=\frac n 2-\frac {\sqrt n } 2 \sqrt{W(t)}\qquad \text{where} \qquad t=\frac 12\left(\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)} \right)^2$$ $W(.)$ being Lambert function. So, as expected earlier, a logarithmic contribution in the asymptotics of $m$.

Comment: How does a $c$ of $1.04$ (or an $m=a+bn\log n$ model, as you suggest) even make sense in your last model? It means you'd have $m\gt n$ for sufficiently large $n$...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki. If you look at my last update, you will see that the asymptotics of $m$ contains a logarithmic contribution because of Lambert function.