# Bounding sum over binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients

How can I show that $ \sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{n}{k} \leq (n+1)^m$ for $m \leq n $?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(n+1)^m
=\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k}n^k
$
so if
$n^k\binom{m}{k}
\ge \binom{n}{k}
$
we are done.

$\begin{array}\\
\binom{m}{k}
&=\dfrac{m!}{k!(m-k)!}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(m-j)}{k!}\\
\dfrac{n^k\binom{m}{k}}{\binom{n}{k}}
&=\dfrac{n^k\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(m-j)}{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n-j)}\\
&\ge\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(m-j)
\qquad\text{since } n^k \ge \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n-j)\\
&\ge 1\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: I do not know why this question has been closed since the summation is up to $m$ and not $n$. Interested by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3912163/sum-of-binomial-coefficients-so-that-the-sum-equals-n-choose-n-2/3912290#3912290 I wonder if you are aware fo a "simple" upperbound in order to possibly improve my estimate or at least derive the asymptotics. Thank you.

Comment: I agree. I find it surprising the number of questions which are incorrectly closed. So I voted to reopen. At least it turns out that there is a simple answer.

Comment: I found a very interesting approximation in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103280/asymptotics-for-a-partial-sum-of-binomial-coefficients which allows a good approximation (if you have time to waste, have a look at my last update in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3912163/sum-of-binomial-coefficients-so-that-the-sum-equals-n-choose-n-2/3912290#3912290  )